# Mocking indexed property

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am writing unit tests using Moq. I have created a mock object. Now when i try to mock its property i am getting error "An expression tree may not contain an indexed property"

here is my code.

```
public Node GetNode(IMyInterface interface, string itemName)
{
    return interface.Items[itemName];
}
```

Here is the unit test

```
var expected = new Node();
var itemName = "TestName";
var mock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
mock.Setup(f => f.Items[itemName]).Returns(expected);
var target = new MyClass();

var actual = target.GetNode(mock.Object, itemName);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

This line is giving me error.

```
mock.Setup(f => f.Items[itemName]).Returns(expected);
```

How can i moq this function.

Comment: That's not a moq problem. Expression trees cannot contain indexed properties as the error states. You should refactor your code to access the item in the list wihtout resorting to indexes.

Comment: i cannot change "interface.Items[itemName];" because i am getting it through COM, any way to do this in test,

Comment: What exactly is Items? Can you provide the full interface definition?

Comment: its a list of Node (a class),

Comment: Well since the whole point of abstraction is to decouple interface from implementation and, to a certain degree, to simplify things, if it is indeed a generic List<Node> and you're testing the interface property, you can retrieve the item by name using a linq operator. Inside your property you will do the linq-COM translation.

Comment: ok i fixed it, there was a function get_Items(string name), i am using method and mocking this,

Comment: It's OK (and actually recommended) to answer you own question once you figure out the resolution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interface was a COM object and there were get function, so instead of directly accessing property using indexer use get function,

```
mock.Setup(f => f.get_Items(itemName)).Returns(expected);
```

Comment: Did you try `mock.Setup(f => f[itemName]).Returns(expected);`? Not sure if it works in your situation (COM) (what C# and .NET versions?), but looks a lot better.

Comment: this is no longer valid for new versions of moq, see Thorkil reply

Answer (score 3):

Using Moq in ASP.NET Core 2.2, the get_Items setup does not work. But this does:

```
Mock<IConfiguration> configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
configuration.Setup(x => x[key]).Returns(value);
```