# Setting property Row to Mocked Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range with Mock

Tags: c#, excel, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I want to mock the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range and after to be able to get property Row (index of first Row of Range). Moq v 4.1.1309.1617 / nunit.framework v 2.6.3.13283
In my unit test, I attempt to set up the behavior of the mock as follows:

```
var moqRowSelected = new Mock<Range>();
const int row = 1;
moqRowSelected.SetupGet(x => x.Row).Returns(row);
moqSheetBase.SetupProperty(x => x.RowSelected, moqRowSelected.Object);
```

In the code being unit tested, I'm using the Range as follows:

```
var iRow = PlanningSheet.RowSelected.Row;
Range row = sheet.Rows[iRow];
```

When the test runs, it produces the following exception:

> Error: Missing method 'instance int32
>   [My.Example.Implementation.MyClass]
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range::get_Row()' from class
>   'Castle.Proxies.RangeProxy'.

How can I implement this mocking successfully? Can any one help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have correctly mocked the object referenced by *PlanningSheet.RowSelected*, therefore the *iRow* should be correct. However you do not have correctly mocked the Range returned by *sheet.Rows*

Let us rewrite the code under test as follow

```
 var iRow = PlanningSheet.RowSelected.Row;
 Range rows = sheet.Rows;
 Range row = rows.get_Range(iRow);
```

I bet that the mock contained in the variable *rows* does not contain a implementation for get_Range() whose is the method behing the indexed property.

Personally, I avoid indexed property because of mocking issue see
[Mocking indexed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520291/mocking-indexed-property)

So here is the code that seems to enable mocking in your case. Note that I do not have access to the type of PlanningSheet so I pass the object referenced by the property RowSelected as a parameter of the method *CodeUnderTest*

```
    private Range CodeUnderTest(Range rowSelected, Worksheet worksheet)
    {
        int index = rowSelected.Row;
        var range = worksheet.Rows.get_Range(index);
        return (Range) range;

    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MySampleTest()
    {
        var moqRowSelected = new Mock<Range>();
        const int row = 1;
        moqRowSelected.SetupGet(x => x.Row).Returns(row);

        var moqRows = new Mock<Range>();
        moqRows.Setup(x => x.get_Range(It.Is<object>( (i) => (int) i==row),It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(moqRowSelected.Object);

        var mockWorksheet = new Mock<Worksheet>();
        mockWorksheet.SetupGet(w => w.Rows).Returns(moqRows.Object);

        var result = CodeUnderTest(moqRowSelected.Object, mockWorksheet.Object);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

Finally you will see that you must provide all the parameters to the method *get_Range* in the mock. This is because if you do not do this, it will not compile. The error is clear *An expression tree cannot contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments*.

Comment: Isn't that limitation for indexers with expression trees only in _older_ versions of C# and .NET? I have used stuff like `someMock.Setup(x => x[row]).Returns(whatever.Object);` sucessfully, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I found the source of problem, is that I should mock any use of Excel property or method, even if it's not in the method that will be tested .For Example : if i use this line `newRow.Rows.AutoFit()` in another method, I should mock it even if i don't need it in the method that will be tested. Now, my problem is with mocking `sheet.Names.Add("D_" + deal.Id, "=" + newRow.Address);` how can I mock it.

Comment: What do you mean by _even if it's not in the method that will be tested_? If the method you are referring to is executed by your unit test, then you will have to mock some of the objects living there...

I think your difficulty in mocking comes from the fact that you think there is one mocked object. For example in `newRow.Rows.Autofit()` you have to mock the method `Autofit()` for the Range instance returned when accessing the property `Rows` for the object referenced by the variable `newRow` which is also a mocked object. To conclude, for this line, you'll need at least two mocks.